# Copying a row from one database table to its twin on a different server through C#

Tags: c#, .net, database, t-sql, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to design a method to allow me to take a row from a SQL database using a SELECT. I then want to INSERT the returned row into an identical table on a database which resides on a different server.

My server connection and SELECT statement both work; I can view the row I want copied in a console window.

The issue I'm having is figuring out what data structure I need to use in C#, how to populate this data structure with the SELECT, and finally how to use that data structure to INSERT the row.

I'd like to keep the option for multiple rows open, but for now if I could get a single row transferring across it would be fantastic.

Thank you.

**Edit:** I've been able to work through this myself after a bunch of research. I've included my code below in the heop it helps someone else, but although it works, it is far from ideal. I am an amateur and it is not yet complete.

```
static public void CopyDatabaseRows(string ConnectionStringDEV, string ConnectionStringLOCAL, string queryString)
{
    //Connect to first database table to retreive row/rows and populate dataset + datatable.
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringDEV);
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, conn);
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, conn);

    dataAdapter.FillSchema(dataSet, SchemaType.Mapped);
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "dbo.FileRegister");
    dataTable = dataSet.Tables["dbo.FileRegister"];
    conn.Close();

    //Connect to second Database and Insert row/rows.
    SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringLOCAL);
    conn2.Open();

    SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn2);
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.FileRegister";
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
}
```

Comment: There are a wide range of ways to do this, and an even wider range of good articles covering these topics.  At what point are you stuck?  How are you implementing your data connections?

Comment: Moving, or copying? There is a fundamental difference.

Comment: Ok, I guess I left it a bit unclear as I've gone down a few different paths and got stuck each time. That's why I left the question a bit more general and didn't include code. I'm leaning towards using a DataAdapter to populate a DataTable, but I wasn;t sure if I was on hte right track. I'll do some more reading and more work and update where exactly I get stuck. I imagine it's going to be getting the row out of the DataSet and into my other table.

Comment: It's copying not moving SolidRegardless. Apologies for being unclear.

Comment: What structure are you reading the data into to display it in the console window?

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest you use something like Simple.Data (https://github.com/markrendle/Simple.Data) to do this really easily. Because it uses C# dynamics, you can just load the dynamic type, and insert it directly into a second Simple.Data connection without worrying about type conversion.

Something like:

```
var db = Database.OpenConnection("data source=.;initial catalog=Xyz;etc");

var db2 = Database.OpenConnection("data source=somewhereElse;initial catalog=Xyz;etc");

dynamic user = db.Users.FindById(1);

db2.Users.Insert(user);
```

Comment: Thank you DavidWhitney. Unfortunately I'm not in a position where I can use something external like this.

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly... I modified this code... Use it...

```
string local = "Server=destinationservername;Database=destinationserverdb;Uid=sa;Pwd=<Password>;

string dev = "Server=sourceservername;Database=sourceserverdb;Uid=sa;Pwd=Password;    


private void btncopy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{            
    CopyDatabaseRows(dev, local, query);            
}

static public void CopyDatabaseRows(string ConnectionStringDEV, string ConnectionStringLOCAL, string queryString)
{
    //Connect to first database table to retreive row/rows and populate dataset + datatable.
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringDEV);
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, conn);
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, conn);

    dataAdapter.FillSchema(dataSet, SchemaType.Mapped);
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "dbo.DeviceLogs");
    dataTable = dataSet.Tables["dbo.DeviceLogs"];
    conn.Close();

    //Connect to second Database and Insert row/rows.
    SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringLOCAL);
    conn2.Open();

    SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn2);
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.DeviceLogs";
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);

    MessageBox.Show(dataTable.Rows.Count.ToString() + "  rows copied successfully", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```